# Ifrit not available when other summons equipped, but is available when it's the only summon equipped

Tags: final-fantasy-7-remake

I'm playing FF7 remake and I noticed that when I was doing the VR battle against Shiva that the only summon that was coming up was Cactuar (was equipped on Aerith).  I saw a post where someone recommended having Ifrit equipped for this battle (which makes sense).  I noticed that a different character (Cloud) already had that summoning materia equipped as well, but I never saw it as available.

When I removed Cactuar from Aerith and re-did the fight Ifrit showed up as expected.  Why is it that Ifrit only shows up as a use-able summon in the Shiva virtual when Cactuar is not equipped on another character?  I have not tried all permutations of all materia possibilities, etc.  But I was able to verify that when Cactuar and Ifrit are both equipped to characters that Cactuar is the only summon that is ever able to be chosen.  When I remove Cactuar, Ifrit shows up as expected in this fight

Comment: @musefan Looking at the other question, I actually don't think this is a duplicate. That question describes a situation where a summon won't show up at all, due to a too-small battle arena. In this person's question, Ifrit clearly isn't too small to show up in that arena since they were able to summon him once they de-equipped Cactuar.

Comment: @lamprey the question is the same "how does the game determine which summons can be used". Just because the answer mentions arena size, that doesnt change what the question is.

Comment: @musefan yes but arena size doesn't answer my question.  The question posed shows that Ifrit CAN be used but isn't being used in a certain situation.  That's not the same as the other question.  I've edited the question topic but the other question is different than this IMO

Comment: @sedavidw: I didn't say the answer is correct for your situation, but the question is the same. If there are other reasons that have not been listed in that answer, then it warrants a better answer, but I for one don't know what that better answer is, so can only wait for somebody to post a better answer... the reality is, I don't think there is any information on the internet that explains this problem so it's hard for people to answer

Comment: @musefan okay well now the answer is edited to be different so it shouldn't be closed because it doesn't have an answer and the other post doesn't answer this question

Comment: Personally, I am not sure I believe what you are saying is correct. Perhaps you didn't have enough ATB to summon Ifrit with Cloud at the time? Have you been able to replicate the problem?

Comment: @musefan I can replicate the issue and yes Cloud did have enough ATB

Comment: So why don't you list the steps to replicate the issue and then make the question more specific to it being a problem with using Cactuar. As it stands you are still only asking "what determines which summon shows up..." which is the same as the duplicate. Maybe you should put "Why does using Cactuar prevent me from using the Ifrit summon?"

Comment: I agree with @musefan here. The question, no matter how it's phrased, we're still talking about criteria used to perform a summon. Which is covered in the other question. As mentioned, answers are not relevant to if a question is marked duplicate. The topic is key, and here, that topic is summon criteria, which is duplicate.

Comment: I actually disagree that this is a dupe; this isn’t a question about criteria, it’s about behavior that appears to be, honestly, a bug. It’s definitely not related to the issue described in the other question, which is “some summons sometimes can’t be used”, it’s “why doesn’t this specific summon work in an environment where it’s been established that it should?”

Comment: Perhaps clarification of the actual behaviour of ifrit+cactaur vs ifrit solo would help?

Comment: @DavidYell I tried to add more clarity around that.  Let me know if it's unclear